Construction of retraction morphism onto the central fiber of the family
Let $f:X\to S$ be a flat proper surjective morphism betweem complex analytic spaces. Is it possible to find some (Euclidean) open neighborhood $0\in U \subset S$ such that there exist a retraction morphism $$r: f^{-1}(U)\to X_0$$

For smooth morphism, the result is clear, by the Ehresmann's theorem. For the semi-stable family over the disc I have the following result in Peters and Steenbrink book of Mixed Hodge Structures:

Proposition C.11. Let $X$ be a manifold and let $f: X \rightarrow \Delta$ be a proper map which is smooth over $\Delta^*$. Put $X_0=f^{-1}(0)$. There is a fibrewise retraction $r: X \rightarrow X_0$. In particular, the homotopy type of $X$ is that of the central fibre.

I found a proof of this result in here, the question that I am asking is can we go further beyond the statement of the Proposition C.11.? To be more precise, can we remove the smoothness assumption on $X$ and replace $\Delta$ by higher dimension variety, and semi-stable assumption?
